# Nothing happens when I click a <button> inside an <a>

Tags: html

I Put `<button>` tag inside `<a>` tag with, but when I click the button nothing happens.

I have this HTML code:

```html
<form>
    <h1>نوع الغرفة </h1>
    <input placeholder="جناح رئاسي , سويت , شاليه "  type="text"> *ضروري
    <h1>عدد الأسرة</h1>
    <input placeholder="2,3,4,1,5 "  type="text">  *ضروري
    <h1>تاريخ الوصول</h1>
    <input placeholder="21/4 , 22/4 "  type="text"> *ضروري
    <h1>ايام الاقامة </h1>
    <input placeholder="يومين , ثلاثة ايام , اربعة ايام , الخ ..."  type="text"> *ضروري
    <h1>الاسم الكريم  </h1>
    <input placeholder="الاسم الكامل "  type="text"> *ضروري
    <h1>كلمة السر الشخصية</h1>
    <input placeholder="الرجاء حفظ الكلمة لانها ضرورية "  type="password"> *ضروري
    <br>
    <hr>
    <a href="indexx.html" target="_blank">
        <button type="submit">Submiit</button>
    </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="indexx.html"> <button type="button">Submiit</button></a>
```

Also does indexx.html is in same folder or it is in sub folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to submit to index.html set that as the action of the form and remove the `<a>`

```
<form action="index.html" method="GET" target="_blank">
   <!-- various inputs -->

   <button type="submit">Submiit</button>
</form>
```